# Spring Kafka Consumer Moving to next Offset even though offset is not committed

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring kafka consumer which reads messages from a kafka topic with 10 partitons, I have only 1 instance of kafka consumer running. I am manually committing the offset and disabled the auto-commit, I am logging which offset consumer is processing and even though there is exception when processing message and offset is not committed, consumer is moving to next offset. How is this possible.

Spring Kafka config:

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> uploadFileConsumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
       props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
       props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   " +
               "required username='"+kafkaUsername+"'   password='"+kafkaPassword+"';");
       props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
       props.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStoreLoc);
       props.put("ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePassword);

       //retry backoff ms
       //Error handler retries

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
    }

   @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> uploadFileConsumerKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(uploadFileConsumerFactory());
        factory.setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new KafkaErrorHandler());
        return factory;
    }
```

Application Logs

```
s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] **Found no committed offset for partition** pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-0
2024-01-19 16:57:01.717  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-1
2024-01-19 16:57:01.717  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-2
2024-01-19 16:57:01.717  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-3
2024-01-19 16:57:01.717  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-4
2024-01-19 16:57:01.719  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-5
2024-01-19 16:57:01.719  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-6
2024-01-19 16:57:01.719  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-7
2024-01-19 16:57:01.719  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-8
2024-01-19 16:57:01.719  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Found no committed offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-9
2024-01-19 16:57:01.896  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-2 to position FetchPosition{offset=684457, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-11:32401 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=74}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.896  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-5 to position FetchPosition{offset=674758, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-11:32401 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=74}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.898  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-8 to position FetchPosition{offset=687910, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-11:32401 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=74}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.909  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=684558, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-10:32400 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=70}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.909  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-3 to position FetchPosition{offset=680112, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-10:32400 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=69}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.909  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-6 to position FetchPosition{offset=691661, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[-10:32400 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=70}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.909  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-9 to position FetchPosition{offset=702081, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{ (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=68}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.916  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-1 to position FetchPosition{offset=678786, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[ (id: 2 rack: null)], epoch=81}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.916  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-4 to position FetchPosition{offset=682934, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[ (id: 2 rack: null)], epoch=80}}.
2024-01-19 16:57:01.916  INFO 22380 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-episteme-s3-downloader-v4-1, groupId=episteme-s3-downloader-v4] Resetting offset for partition pp.qmct.s3.file.tracker-7 to position FetchPosition{offset=674101, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional

2024-01-19 16:36:51.852  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : **Current offset: 674101**
2024-01-19 16:36:51.852  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Device Mode: EUT
2024-01-19 16:36:51.852  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Received S3 key: 20240118/73dbf7e6-873a-41c7-b1ed-63f37b8f7fda/68f18ff4-cd96-43de-8041-561e17f8d2bb/646631341.1705570404281
2024-01-19 16:36:51.853  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : DeviceId: 73dbf7e6-873a-41c7-b1ed-63f37b8f7fda, FileUID: 68f18ff4-cd96-43de-8041-561e17f8d2bb, FileName: 646631341.1705570404281.
2024-01-19 16:36:51.853  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Downloading an object with key= 20240118/73dbf7e6-873a-41c7-b1ed-63f37b8f7fda/68f18ff4-cd96-43de-8041-561e17f8d2bb/646631341.1705570404281
2024-01-19 16:36:52.304 ERROR 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Exception while downloading key from s3 buckets: 
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305 ERROR 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Exception Trace: {}[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@14afe3b8
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Total time taken to process file 68f18ff4-cd96-43de-8041-561e17f8d2bb in ms: 453
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : **Current offset: 674102**
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Device Mode: EUT
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Received S3 key: 20240118/9e93b360-f8e4-44e8-988c-64a26538b017/f93f19f1-004c-45fe-8791-81fe282e7d95/646631341.1705570405539
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : DeviceId: 9e93b360-f8e4-44e8-988c-64a26538b017, FileUID: f93f19f1-004c-45fe-8791-81fe282e7d95, FileName: 646631341.1705570405539.
2024-01-19 16:36:52.305  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Downloading an object with key= 20240118/9e93b360-f8e4-44e8-988c-64a26538b017/f93f19f1-004c-45fe-8791-81fe282e7d95/646631341.1705570405539
2024-01-19 16:36:52.367 ERROR 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Exception while downloading key from s3 buckets: Access Denied 
2024-01-19 16:36:52.367 ERROR 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Exception Trace: {}[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@74072ede
2024-01-19 16:36:52.367  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : Total time taken to process file f93f19f1-004c-45fe-8791-81fe282e7d95 in ms: 62
2024-01-19 16:36:52.367  INFO 15796 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.q.episteme.consumer.KafkaConsumers     : **Current offset: 674103**
```

Consumer code in case of Exception

```
catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("Exception while downloading key from s3 buckets: {}", ex.getMessage());
            log.error("Exception Trace: {}" +ex.getStackTrace());
            if(ex instanceof AmazonS3Exception && ((AmazonS3Exception) ex).getStatusCode()== 404){
                log.info("The S3 key: {} doesn't exists in S3 bucket", s3Key);
                log.info("Committing the offset: {}", offset);
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            }

        }
        log.info("Total time taken to process file {} in ms: {}",fileUid, (System.currentTimeMillis()- startTimeMsMessage));
    }
'''
```

Comment: What is your consumer doing, code? Also what is `KafkaErrorHandler` doing? If the offset is moving something that you missed is committing the offset somewhere. Try enabling Trace mode for logs so you can see if there are any clues.

Comment: No Actually offset is not committing because if I run the application again with the same consumer, it is reading those messages again, if offset had been committed it would have not read those messages again.

Comment: Consumer is catching the exception and checking if it is 404, then commit the offset, for others don't commit, since I am catching the exception, code is not going to KafkaErrorHandler.

Comment: your first comment here confused the heck out of me... had to read it many times over. So your application while running is theoretically moving the offsets (aka committing) **when it shouldn't** BUT if you restart your application it consumes the sames messages again, did I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly liking the consumer group is getting rebalanced and the consumer is reading the message from other partition. Check if Max poll time value getting exceeded or try setting the keep alive setting for client configuration